# How to fix and add contents on app before release to play store

Tags: android, ios

I asked this but nobody answered. So I'm putting this up again.

I'm newbie to making app. I managed to complete but it wasn't completed when i did test on my phone. I didn't release my app, yet. I need to fix some things and i don't know how to make it. my app is web view app. I found some errors.

1. when I click 'back' button of my phone, app just shut down. -> I want it to go back page.
2. I have sharing icon and it works on computer but not in phone. -> I want it to be shared through the phone, too.

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

for first issue of back button:

In your Activity where you initiated webview

```
private WebView mWebView;   // make accessible outside oncreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youre_activity);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); // in oncreate your webview
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { //// after oncreate override back key event
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

For Second issue of sharing you need to use andtoid sharing intent and trigger it from your webview. follow the tutorial below

https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/

Comment: thank you. for the first one i should add it to my json file?

Comment: No add it to android activity java file

Comment: Sorry but i can't find any activity file in my list. But i have 'app.js' file. Is it?